# Expression cannot be assigned on SOQL object

Tags: apex, aura

I am getting Expression cannot be assigned on size(). Not sure why?

```
public static void setAppData(String setUserId){
List<UserAppInfoHistory__c> UAIHistory = new List<UserAppInfoHistory__c>();
UserAppInfo UAI = [select UserId, AppDefinitionId, FormFactor, LastModifiedDate from UserAppInfo where UserId = :setUserId];
UAIHistory = [select Accessed_On__c, AppDefinitionId__c, App_Name__c, Id, Name, OwnerId, UserId__c, User__c from MIO_USPA_UserAppInfoHistory__c where AppDefinitionId__c = :UAI.AppDefinitionId and UserId__c = :setUserId and Accessed_On__c = :UAI.LastModifiedDate];
if(UAIHistory.size()=0){
//do something
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equality operator is `==` i.e. you need `UAIHistory.size() == 0`.

Do format your code to help you and others read your code more easily:

```
public static void setAppData(String userId){

    UserAppInfo uai = [
        select UserId, AppDefinitionId, FormFactor, LastModifiedDate 
        from UserAppInfo
        where UserId = :userId
    ];

    List<UserAppInfoHistory__c> uaiHistory = [
        select Accessed_On__c, AppDefinitionId__c, App_Name__c, Id, Name, OwnerId, UserId__c, User__c
        from MIO_USPA_UserAppInfoHistory__c 
        where AppDefinitionId__c = :uai.AppDefinitionId
        and UserId__c = :userId
        and Accessed_On__c = :uai.LastModifiedDate
    ];

    if (uaiHistory.size() == 0) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

and FYI [Apex lists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm) also have an `isEmpty` method so you could use that instead:

```
    if (uaiHistory.isEmpty()) {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: What is confusing: in SOQL WHERE clauses you must use =. In Apex conditions you must use ==. So much for consistency.

Comment: Yeah @SanderdeJong; SOQL following SQL rather than being consistent with Apex.